# URL redirection for duplicate content

Tags: seo, canonical-url

I have submitted a site to Google and a lot of pages which I was never aware of, got indexed. These are duplicate contents:

Example:

```
site.com/photos-menu/content/photos1/?start=210
site.com/photos-menu/content/photos1/?start=50
site.com/photos-menu/content/photos1/
```

etc...

I have removed them 'temporarily' in Google Search Console and am trying to find a way so Google don't index them again.

What would be a good SEO way to tackle this ?

Answer (score 1):

The first question is, do you need these pages on your website a tall? Since you had said you weren't aware of these pages, I'm going to guess not. If that is the case, your best answer would be to delete these duplicate pages from your website and allow them to return a 404/Not Found error message. That tells Google (and human visitors) that you don't want those pages to be associated with your website.

My second question is do these pages get any traffic right now or do they have any backlinks? If yes, you may want to redirect these somewhere else on your website. It looks like these are related to photos, so if you have a gallery or something like that on your website, maybe you could redirect these URLs there. However, if these URLs don't have any traffic or backlinks (or only very little or poor quality), then you don't need to redirect these. A redirect only matters if you are trying to capture some value within these pages.

I hope that helps!