# Use RedirectMatch in htaccess for many URLs

Tags: htaccess, web-hosting, 301-redirect

I need to redirect:

```
https://example.com/thispath/beach?start=20
https://example.com/thispath/beach?start=40
https://example.com/thispath/beach?start=60
```

etc...

to:

```
https://example.com/thispath/beach
```

there are other URLs such as :

```
https://example.com/thispath/sunset?start=20
https://example.com/thispath/sunset?start=40
https://example.com/thispath/sunset?start=60
etc....
```

which will need to be redirected to :

```
https://example.com/thispath/sunset
```

and

```
    https://example.com/menu-alias/content/cat-alias/?start=210
https://example.com/menu-alias/content/cat-alias/?start=105
```

to

```
https://example.com/menu-alias/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a mod_alias `RedirectMatch` here because `RedirectMatch` matches against the requested URL-path only, not the query string. To match the query string you need to use mod_rewrite (`RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives) and match against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable in a *condition*.

For example, to redirect `/thispath/beach?start=<number>` you can do something like the following near the top of your root `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=\d+$
RewriteRule ^thispath/beach$ /$0 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

Note that this matches `?start=<number>` (case-sensitive) as in your examples, it does not match `?start=` or `?start=abc` or `?foo=1&start=<number>` or `?Start=<Number>`.

The `QSD` flag (Apache 2.4) discards the query string from the request.

`$0` is a backreference that contains the entire match from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, so it basically redirects to the same URL-path, just less the query string.

You can modify the above rule to match `/thispath/sunset?start=<number>` as well by using *alternation* in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. For example:

```
:
RewriteRule ^thispath/(?:beach|sunset)$ /$0 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `?:` prefix inside the parenthesised group makes it non-capturing.

> `https://example.com/menu-alias/content/cat-alias/?start=210` to `https://example.com/menu-alias/`

This is a little different and is better served with an additional rule. For example:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=\d+$
RewriteRule ^(menu-alias/)content/cat-alias/$ /$1 [QSD,R=301,L]
```

The `$1` backreference matches the first capturing group from the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. ie. `menu-alias/` in this case.

NB: Test first with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid potential caching issues.

*Aside:* From your [earlier question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/136125/url-redirection-for-duplicate-content) it looks like this URL parameter might be used by your website (as part of a *photo gallery* perhaps)? If this is the case then *redirection* is not the correct action. ([The answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/136129/1243) on that question raised this same concern but received no response.)

---

**UPDATE:** For `example.com/menu-alias/content/cat-alias/?start=210`  etc... I want to throw a 404 error instead.

To trigger a 404 instead change the `RewriteRule` directive to read:

```
:
RewriteRule ^menu-alias/content/cat-alias/$ - [R=404]
```

No *susbstitution* string is required (denoted by the `-` argument). The `L` flag is not required when used with a non-3xx return status; it is implied.

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation

For
'
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^start=\d+$
RewriteRule ^thispath/(?:beach|sunset)$ /$0 [QSD,R=301,L]
'
This works perfectly !

For
'    https://example.com/menu-alias/content/cat-alias/?start=210
https://example.com/menu-alias/content/cat-alias/?start=105
https://example.com/menu-alias/content/cat-alias
etc...'
I want to throw a 404 error instead.

Comment: @Goble I've updated my answer to return a 404 instead for that rule.

Comment: Hi sorry, I searched before but could not find the checkmark. Just done ! Thanks for guiding me where it was.